# How to make a C++ intention list

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, containers, std

I would like to make an intention list like python does.

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
newList = [ i * 2 for i in list ]
```

Using std,iterator and lambda function, it should be possible to do the same things in one line.

```
std::vector<int> list = {1,2,3,4} ; 
std::vector<int> newList =
```

Could you complete it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) lets you transform values and put them somewhere else:

```
std::vector<int> list = {1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> newList;

std::transform(
    list.cbegin(),
    list.cend(),
    back_inserter(newList),
    [](int x) { return x * 2; });
```

But really, C++ is not the language for conciseness.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution. But it's not very nice .

```
std::vector<int> list = {1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> newList;
std::for_each(list.begin(), list.end(),[&newList](int val){newList.push_back(val*2);});
```

Comment: `for_each` makes much less sense these days when range-for is on the track.